# Emoji and strikethroughStyle issue

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to use `strikethroughStyle` on string with emoji "Belka ". And line for text and emoji breaks. How to fix that? Maybe there is another way to reach this (some lifehacks such as find text frame and add line on it)?

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
                .strikethroughStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                .strikethroughColor : UIColor.black
            ]
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Belka ",
                                          attributes: attributes)
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

[image: Screenshot, strikethrough line on emoji is higher than the text's]

Comment: You could try a different `.baselineOffset` value for `textAttributes` vs `emojiAttributes`. That'd be a work-around rather than a solution.